# Problem with special filenames when trying to pull android files into windows pc recursively using adb

Tags: android, linux, bash, command-line, adb

I want to download all files from `/data/data/foo` folder to my `pc`. I am using `adb` to connect with my phone.

```
cd /data/data/foo
ls -R
.:
    cache
    databases
    files
    lib
    shared_prefs

./cache:

./databases:
    errors.db
    errors.db-journal
    logs.db
    logs.db-journal

./files:
cache_state.info

./shared_prefs:
LANG_CODE.xml
PPP.xml
CADD
.xml
```

To download files I am using:

```
adb pull "/data/data/foo" %USERPROFILE%/foo
```

And here's response:

```
pull: building file list...
skipping special file 'lib'
pull: /data/data/foo/files/cache_state.info -> C:\Users\root/foo/files/cache_state.info
pull: /data/data/foo/shared_prefs/CADD
.xml -> C:\Users\root/foo/shared_prefs/CADD
.xml
cannot create 'C:\Users\root\foo\shared_prefs\CADD
.xml': No such file or directory
```

And in fact, only this is copied:

```
foo/files/cache_state.info
foo/shared_prefs
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the issue is that it is unable to copy `.xml` and then it aborts. If you're trying to copy a unix filesystem into a windows filesystem you might run into issues with files whose names are valid in unix but invalid in windows cannot be copied.

Comment: Sorry, on a second read I think it's a bit different. I thought that there was a file named `CADD` and another one named `.xml`, but now I think it's only one file and the filename includes a line break (`CADD\n.xml`)

Comment: @brunorey I think you're right. I checked using `ls -l` and it seems that there is additional `\n`

Comment: See [Which file systems support newlines in file names?](https://superuser.com/questions/129519/which-file-systems-support-newlines-in-file-names)

Comment: Which windows are you using? If you have access to an _ext_ filesystem try to copy your files there instead. Otherwise, consider that new Windows versions have incorporated a _bash_ shell that runs on ubuntu. You might try to copy these files there ([info](https://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/)). If you do, be very careful when manipulating this filesystem.

Comment: @brunorey I am using Windows 10 and Git Bash

Comment: I've posted an answer. I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**

What you're doing is right (the command is correct), but the problem comes from the nature of the task you're trying to achieve.

You're trying to copy files from a unix device (an ext filesystem) into your windows pc (with NTFS filesystem). This usually works fine but there are cases when it doesn't: different filesystems have different rules as to which filenames are valid, and if a filename is valid in the source but not in the destination, there's no way to copy it preserving it's name.

From the error I understand you have a file named `CADD
.xml` (with line break included in the name) that is valid in your android device but will give an error when trying to copy it into your windows filesystem (see [Which file systems support newlines in file names?](https://superuser.com/questions/129519/which-file-systems-support-newlines-in-file-names)).

**Possible solutions:**

- Copy the files one by one and set a different destination name for the file causing trouble (`CADD\n.xml` -> `CADD.xml`)
- Get some `ext` filesystem (either create it in your disk or mount from an external disk) and copy the files there
- Copy the file into the `ext` filesystem used by your in-windows bash shell (see [How to Access Your Ubuntu Bash Files in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/) )

Comment: Came here in 2022 just to say thank you! Last line is the right way for me! Ubuntu even uses the current live server from your Windows exe.